# Put Rails delegated methods in columns_hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delegates

I have two Ruby classes in a Rails app, `Foo` and `Bar`. `Foo` has-many `Bar`s. `Foo` has the following delegation:

`delegate :bar_method, to: :bar`

Is there a way to get `bar_method` to show up in `Foo`'s `columns_hash`?

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you have a class Foo and it `has_many :bars` then an instance of Foo doesn't have a Bar, it has a collection of Bars. So your `delegate :bar_method, to: :bar` won't work because there is no bar.

That being said, if instead class Foo `has_one :bar` and then you `delegate :bar_method, to: :bar` then you can just adjust the columns_hash method.

Rails is just Ruby and so you can just use Ruby

```
def self.columns_hash
  super.merge('bar_method' => Bar.columns_hash['bar_method'])
end
```